# if statements and relational and comparison operators: "Exceptions" When comparing three values/variables

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparison-operators

**Context**

Taking a c++ course and if statements and relational and comparison operators came up. I don't know enough c++ vocabulary so I apologize if this question has been asked before. I tried searching around, but I didn't find anything.

**Problem**

Below illustrates an example of what I am confused about.

```
int n = 1;

if(2 < n <1){
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

When the program is ran, the cout statement gets printed to the console (which is surprising to me).

**Question**

How is C++ interpreting the values and relational and comparison operators within the if statement?

If there are any other interesting "exceptions" like this documented somewhere could you please reference it for me, thank you.

**Ans Attempt**

I'm not totally sure what is going on. To me it seems like the middle number is getting skipped?

After playing with the numbers a few times I've now been able to confirm that the middle number is getting skipped, but I have no idea why.

If I add arguments by scaling the problem up:

```
if(2 < n < 0 <1){
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

and also:

```
if(2 < n < 1 < 1 < 1){
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Now I get really confused. It seems like whatever "thing" is in the middle gets ignored. But I found an exception to my pattern when n = 3 causes the if statement to be "false":

```
int n = 3 
if(2 < n < 1 < 1 <1){
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

But then if I change n to what seems like "any" (not exhaustive) other number the if statement will yield true again.

Comment: `if(2 < n <1){` is only useful if you're trying to win an award for best obfuscated code.

Comment: I definitely understand your confusion, but do keep in mind this behavior is not an "exception". It's a consistent application of the language's rules. In fact, interpreting `2 < n < 1` as `2 < n && n < 1` (as Python does) is really more of an exception to a rule. It's a very helpful exception, and it feels very good to have, but nonetheless it's a divergence from the usual rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `2 < n < 1` ain't does what you think it should:

> Because these operators group left-to-right, the expression `a<b<c` is
> parsed `(a<b)<c`, and not `a<(b<c)` or `(a<b)&&(b<c)` - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Notes)

The `2 < n` part will return a Boolean value which in turn will be compared in the `< 1`.

```
2 < n < 1;
// equal to 
(2 < n) < 1;
```

So, in total, the `2 < n < 1` flows like so:

- `(2 < n) < 1`. Is n greater than 2? No, return `false`.
- `false < 1`. The `false` is [promoted to an integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion), to 0. Is 0 less than 1? Yes, the `if` condition is `true`.

That's why when `n == 3` in the `2 < n < 1 < 1 < 1`, the overall you get `false`:

- `(2 < 3) < 1 < 1 < 1`. Is 3 greater than 2? Yes! Returns `1` (`true`)
- `(1 < 1) < 1 < 1`. Is 1 less than 1? No! Return `0` (`false`)
- `(0 < 1) < 1`. Is 0 less than 1? Yes! Return `1` (`true`)
- `1 < 1`. Is 1 less than 1? No! Return `0` (`false`)

It is nonsensical as you can see. In order to make it work, you will have to make explicit checks:

```
(n < 2) && (n > 1)
// is n less than 2 AND is n greater than 1
```